# Return a sum or 0 if a range is true/false in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm a new teacher and i was trying to write a program in excel that helps students with a maximum of 5 marks if needed to pass.

As an example:

- if a student gets 46 I'd give him 4 marks.
- if the student gets 49 I'd give him 1 mark.
- if the student gets 44 or 50 he gets 0.

I want to write a formula in the column K that gives values from 0 to 5.

Not using excel before I tried `=IF((44<J3<50),50-J3,0)` for student A but got `0` and everyone else got the same `0`.

Comment: `=IF(AND(44<J3,J3<50),50-J3,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

IF(OR(B2<=44,B2>=50),0,50-B2)

[image]

Of course you could do this:

```
IF(OR(50-B2>5,50-B2<=0),0,50-B2)
```

Based on the comment by User1122393 :
tested with more values:
[image]

Comment: tried it but help for student H returned -20 making his final mark 50 (it was 70)

Comment: @HaiderAlfatlawi so check the edit.

Comment: @user11222393 see the edit.